# Pandas unable to reset index because name exist

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-level pandas dataframe which im trying to level. I use reset_index but its giving me error that the name already exist.

I dont want to use `reset_index(drop=True)` because i want to keep one of the column names still.

[image]

i want as my new dataframe:

**country,listing_neighborhood,count**

**right now,**

`df.columns` only gives `count`.

**my code:**

```
df.columns = ['count']
df.reset_index() -> gives error that `ValueError: cannot insert country, already exists`
```

**I also tried:**

`df.columns.droplevel(0)` -> gives error that `'Index' object has no attribute 'droplevel'`

Comment: If you have come here because you are having this issue, but your indices are different names, (especially if one of the indices is named 0), you might be trying to reset the index of a series instead of a data frame. When I tried this, my series name was 0 by default, and so when I reset the index there was a duplicate column. I renamed the series and it works fine.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need remove first duplicated level:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

df = (df.set_index(['A','F','C'])
        .rename_axis(['country','country','listing_neighborhood'])
        .rename(columns={'B':'count'}))

print (df)
                                      count
country country listing_neighborhood       
a       a       7                         4
b       a       8                         5
c       a       9                         4
d       b       4                         5
e       b       2                         5
f       b       3                         4

df = df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
  country  listing_neighborhood  count
0       a                     7      4
1       a                     8      5
2       a                     9      4
3       b                     4      5
4       b                     2      5
5       b                     3      4
```

Or:

```
df = df.droplevel(0).reset_index()
```

Comment: @Rob - Added sample data, working well. Maybe your data are different.

Comment: subsequent levels can be deleted by passing level a list. E.g., level=[0,1,2]. Depends on how many indexes were created.

Answer (score 10):

You can change the existing name so that it would not be duplicated anymore:

> df.reset_index(name="new_name")

Hope this help

Comment: "name" isnt a parameter you can pass to reset_index

Comment: "name" is a parameter that you can pass to pd.Series.reset_index. Doing a groupby operation that yields a single column may result in a multi indexed Series which is how I encountered this error: df.groupby(col1).col2.value_counts().reset_index() fails with the OP error however the final step of this process (which appears similar to OP example) is a Series.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have levels in your index with the same name. You can just rename them so that they're unique:

```py
df.index.names = ["country1", "country2", "listing_neighborhood"]
df.reset_index()
```