# How to create a groupby dataframe without a multi-level index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following pandas `groupby` object, and I'd like to turn the result into a new dataframe.

Following, is the code to get the conditional probability:

```
bin_probs = data.groupby('season')['bin'].value_counts()/data.groupby('season')['bin'].count()
```

I've tried the following code, but it returns as follows.

- **I like the `season` to fill in each row. How can I do that?**

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data_5.groupby('season')['bin'].value_counts()/data_5.groupby('season')['bin'].count())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `a` is a DataFrame, but with a 2-level index, so my interpretation is you want a dataframe without a multi-level index.

  - The index can't be reset when the name in the index and the column are the same.
  - Use [`pandas.Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), and set `name='normalized_bin`, to rename the `bin` column.

    - This would not work with the implementation in the OP, because that is a dataframe.
    - This works with the following implementation, because a `pandas.Series` is created with `.groupby`.
- The correct way to normalize the column is to use the `normalize=True` parameter in [`.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import random  # for test data
import numpy as np  # for test data

# setup a dataframe with test data
np.random.seed(365)
random.seed(365)
rows = 1100
data = {'bin': np.random.randint(10, size=(rows)),
        'season': [random.choice(['fall', 'winter', 'summer', 'spring']) for _ in range(rows)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df.head())
   bin  season
0    2  summer
1    4  winter
2    1  summer
3    5  winter
4    2  spring

# groupby, normalize and reset the the Series index
a = df.groupby(['season'])['bin'].value_counts(normalize=True).reset_index(name='normalized_bin')

# display(a.head(15))
    season  bin  normalized_bin
0     fall    2         0.15600
1     fall    9         0.11600
2     fall    3         0.10800
3     fall    4         0.10400
4     fall    6         0.10000
5     fall    0         0.09600
6     fall    8         0.09600
7     fall    5         0.08400
8     fall    7         0.08000
9     fall    1         0.06000
10  spring    0         0.11524
11  spring    8         0.11524
12  spring    9         0.11524
13  spring    3         0.11152
14  spring    1         0.10037
```

### Using the OP code for `a`

- As already noted above, use `normalize=True` to get normalized values
- The solution in the OP, creates a DataFrame, because the `.groupby` is wrapped with the DataFrame constructor, `pandas.DataFrame`.

  - To reset the index, you must first [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the `bin` column, and then use [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```py
a = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('season')['bin'].value_counts()/df.groupby('season')['bin'].count()).rename(columns={'bin': 'normalized_bin'}).reset_index()
```

### Other Resources

- See [Pandas unable to reset index because name exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761486) to reset by a `level`.

### Plotting

- It is easier to plot from the multi-index Series, by using [`pandas.Series.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), and then use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)
- For side-by-side bars, set `stacked=False`.
- The bars are all equal to 1, because this is normalized data.

```py
s = df.groupby(['season'])['bin'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack()

# plot a stacked bar
s.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(8, 6))
plt.legend(title='bin', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Trenton, thank you so much for a detailed explanation and reframe my questions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for parameter [`normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```py
bin_probs = data.groupby('season')['bin'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Read more about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):