# Reseting indexes when I have same name multi index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```py
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('01/01/2020', periods=48, freq='15D'), 
                     'value':np.random.randint(20,30,48)})
mydf
    date        value
0   2020-01-01  20
1   2020-01-16  28
2   2020-01-31  23
3   2020-02-15  27
4   2020-03-01  25
5   2020-03-16  25
...
```

And I want to count the values per each month, so I applied this:

```py
mydf.groupby([mydf['date'].dt.year,mydf['date'].dt.month]).size()
date  date
2020  1       3
      2       1
      3       3
      4       2
      5       2
...
```

Now, I want to reset the indexes, in order to have this expected result:

```py
Year  Month   Size
2020  1       3
2020  2       1
2020  3       3
2020  4       2
2020  5       2
```

So I tried this:

```py
mydf.groupby([mydf['date'].dt.year,mydf['date'].dt.month]).size().\
    to_frame().reset_index()
```

But I received this error:

```py
ValueError: cannot insert date, already exists
```

Then I tried to rename the columns to avoid this problem, but I received a multi index list of tuples, which I don't want:

```py
mydf.groupby([mydf['date'].dt.year,mydf['date'].dt.month]).size().\
    to_frame().rename(columns={0:'Size'}).index.rename(['Year','Month'])
MultiIndex([(2020,  1),
            (2020,  2),
            (2020,  3),
            (2020,  4),
            (2020,  5),
...
```

What I am doing wrong? Please, is that my index name assignment is wrong? Do I have to reset levels or drop levels?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761486/pandas-unable-to-reset-index-because-name-exist). If I understand your question correctly, I believe the solution offered there will help you also.

Comment: Have you checked resampling - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html#pandas.Series.resample ,  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling ? `mydf.set_index('date').resample('1M').count()`  for example, can split & re-arrange columns from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple trick to know is that you can rename series inline like this

Instead of `mydf['date'].dt.year`

Do `mydf['date'].dt.year.rename("year")`.

Comment: By renaming both columns I could create my group by aggregation. Thank you @creanion

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something like:

```
mydf_grouped = mydf.groupby([mydf['date'].dt.year,mydf['date'].dt.month]).size()

mydf_grouped.index.names = ['year', 'month']

mydf_grouped.reset_index()
```

Comment: Interesting approach!