# pandas.DataFrame.groupby loses index and messes up the data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` (named `df`) with the following data:

```
          labels               texts
0         labelA  Some Text 12345678
1         labelA  Some Text 12345678
2         labelA  Some Text 12345678
3         labelA  Some Text 12345678
4         labelB  Some Text 12345678
5         labelB  Some Text 12345678
6         labelB  Some Text 12345678
7         labelC  Some Text 12345678
8         labelC  Some Text 12345678
9         labelC  Some Text 12345678
10        labelC  Some Text 12345678
11        labelC  Some Text 12345678
12        labelC  Some Text 12345678
```

when I perform group by with the following (the goal is to take 2 samples from each label), the index is lost:

```
grouped = df.groupby('labels')
result = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2))
print(result)
```

The output becomes:

```
                    labels               texts
labels
labelA    0         labelA  Some Text 12345678
          0         labelA  Some Text 12345678
          0         labelB  Some Text 12345678
          0         labelB  Some Text 12345678
          0         labelC  Some Text 12345678
          0         labelC  Some Text 12345678
```

I would like the output becomes:

```
          labels               texts
0         labelA  Some Text 12345678
1         labelA  Some Text 12345678
2         labelB  Some Text 12345678
3         labelB  Some Text 12345678
4         labelC  Some Text 12345678
5         labelC  Some Text 12345678
```

How should I make the changes?

I tried to use `result.dropout(0).reset_index()` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48761501/188331), but it becomes:

```
     index         labels               texts
0        0         labelA  Some Text 12345678
1        0         labelA  Some Text 12345678
2        0         labelB  Some Text 12345678
3        0         labelB  Some Text 12345678
4        0         labelC  Some Text 12345678
5        0         labelC  Some Text 12345678
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `group_keys` parameter to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
grouped = df.groupby('labels', group_keys=False)
result = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2))
print(result)

   labels               texts
0  labelA  Some Text 12345678
1  labelA  Some Text 12345678
4  labelB  Some Text 12345678
6  labelB  Some Text 12345678
9  labelC  Some Text 12345678
8  labelC  Some Text 12345678
```

Another idea is remove all index and replace by original default `RangeIndex`:

```
grouped = df.groupby('labels')
result = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2)).reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)
   labels               texts
0  labelA  Some Text 12345678
1  labelA  Some Text 12345678
2  labelB  Some Text 12345678
3  labelB  Some Text 12345678
4  labelC  Some Text 12345678
5  labelC  Some Text 12345678
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However, the first result is still producing a series of `0`. The 2nd solution works. Thanks.